# Problem in invoke sudo make install in python script

Tags: apt, python, python3, execute-command

I have written the following code to configure yara package in my script, but when it call sudo make install, python give me error. How can I fix it?

```
    def yara_installation(self):
    os.chdir("yara/")
    self.installYara = "./bootstrap.sh;./configure;make;sudo make install"
    for self.items in self.installYara.split(";"):
        if (subprocess.run(self.items, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)):
            self.color.print_blue("\t[+] {} command is running.".format(self.items))
        else:
            self.color.print_blue("\t[+] {} command isn't running.".format(self.items))
```

Exception is : [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sudo make install'

Comment: Didn't I mention on your last question that subprocess requires a list ?

Comment: Why run it with `sudo` anyway? Just run the script with `sudo` instead.

Comment: ^ that, what terdon said

Comment: @terdon i do that but it doesn't work yet.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `subprocess.run()` command with this:

```
subprocess.call(self.items, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL,shell=True)
```

This should work, however, I'd personally approach this via using lists, and call specific shell per each shell script. `shell=True` however will call `/bin/sh` on your `bootstrap.sh` ,  which hopefully doesn't contain any bashisms and is portable.